# Error in c programme conflicting types for xx and previous implicit declaration of xx was here

Tags: c, function

Suppose I have a file insert.c in which two functions are defined:
1.insert_after
2.insert_before

The definitions of these func are something like this:

```
insert_after(arg1)
{ 
  if(condition 1)
    { ......... } 
  else
    insert_before(arg1); 
}

insert_before(arg)
{ 
  if(condition 1)
    { ......... } 
  else
    insert_after(arg); 
}
```

Now if this file insert.c is included in main.c and insert_after function is called

```
# include "insert.c"
int main()
{
  insert_after(arg);
  return 0;
}
```

On compiling main.c using gcc,the following error is encountered:

> conflicting types for ‘insert_before’
>
> note: previous implicit declaration of ‘insert_before’ was here

What is wrong here and how to avoid it?

Comment: Please post your actual code. You've got conflicting declarations which could mean no prototype, incorrect prototype, or typos. Impossible to tell with "pseudocode"

Comment: Those aren't function definitions. You're missing the parameter types. Is this the *actual* code that you're trying to compile?

Comment: Can you compile `insert.c` standalone without errors?

Comment: If you are expecting help to eliminate a syntax error, you really should post the *actual code* and the *actual error message and line number*. What you have posted is not very helpful.

Comment: Apart from the answers you'll get, there are a few things to note: 1) Never use implicit types. Be explicit: `int insert_after(int arg)`. 2)  Never `#include` a `.c` file. Create a `.h` file with the prototypes and include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't declare prototypes for your functions. A function which has no prototype, by default, has an unknown set of arguments and returns an int. But this is not the case for `insert_before`.

Create a file `insert.h` in which you declare them:

```
#ifndef INSERT_H
#define INSERT_H

void insert_before(type_of_arg);
void insert_after(type_of_arg);

#endif /* INSERT_H */
```

and include this file at the top of `insert.c`.

You should then compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -o progname insert.c main.c
```

Answer (score 1):

create a `.h` file and give those functions [*prototypes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) (the Wikipedia entry describing prototypes is linked for you).

the `.h` file would contain just the functions:

```
insert_before(arg);
insert_after(arg);
```

Also, you should probably have a return type and a parameter type (e.g. `void insert_before(char * arg);`  Compilers are really good with type checking and it will save you headaches later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `insert_before` before the compiler knows about it. Give them appropriate prototypes (in a header file) and include **the header file** in both insert.c and main.c

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have not declared the functions fully. Each function signature should start with a return variable type, and all arguments should be specified with a type, i.e:

```
void insert_before(int arg)
{
...
}
```

To have two functions call each other, you will need to forward declare one at least, but usually you do it for all your functions and put it in a common `.h` file which gets included in your source files which use that function. These 'forward declarations' are commonly known as function prototypes, and look like this:

```
void insert_before(int arg);
void insert_after(int arg);
```

Indentation is a real problem... that could be a symptom of posting in SO, but posting code on here is also more readable if it is indented.

Also, if condition 1 is the same in both functions, then you will probably have infinite recursive calls which will lead to a stack overflow.